# C# or vba check box

Tags: c#, windows, checkbox

I'm new here and I have a problem (I think the solution is simple, but I can't solve this problem alone). I have to throw a few checkbox on userform (that is simple) but when I write something like this:

```
if(checkBox1.Checked)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ok1");
}
else if(checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ok2");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("co nie tak");
}
```

always get "ok1" MsgBox...

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why do you think you're doing something wrong? The second statement is the one thats evaluating to true

Comment: As it is written it should be impossible to go inside to `ok2`. Need more code

Comment: bryy my Mistake - always got "ok1" MsgBox...

Comment: You should always include your desired behavior in the question. So what else do you expect and what are the individual `Checked` values for each checkbox when you expect some output?

Comment: Ok, then you should just switch them around. Place the condition in the `else if` in the `if` and the `if` condition in the `else if`

Comment: That's not what i need. If i change -else if to if - then when i checked CB1 and CB2 then i see 2 MsgBox(first will see "ok1" after that "ok2"). 
I need to fulfilled the first condition showed a msgbox "OK1" and met with both warynkach showed only "OK2

Comment: All the answers below more or less describes what you have done wrong and how to fix it. If you are in fact wondering about something else, either edit your question or make a new question. And take your time with the problem description to make sure we understand, because you are being very unclear in the comments

Answer (score 1):

The if statement will always go into the first block that is true.  So if checkbox1 is checked you will always get "ok1".  You can never get into the second block ( "ok2" ) because if it is true, the first check would also be true.

I think you want to switch your checks:

```
if(checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ok2");
}
else if(checkBox1.Checked)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ok1");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("co nie tak");
}
```

You may also be looking to build up your string by adding to it.  The += means add to the end of the string.

My example code is just an example, since I don't really know what you are trying to do, but it might give you some ideas.

```
if (checkBox1.checked )
{
  mic.HTMLBody = "1) Example1";
}
if ( checkBox2.checked )
{
  mic.HTMLBody += "<br>"""2) Example2";
  if ( ComboBox2.Text == "Pan" )
  {
     mic.HTMLBody += "<br>Pana";
  }
}
```

Comment: using what (loop, function etc) I can make it work it properly?

Comment: You would switch your checks.  Up to you if you want to switch your messges.

Comment: Derek thx - that's work:) 
But what, when I am 15 and 3 selection combobox ?? ; P I have to start from the loop 15CB and 3 Combo and descend?

Comment: Are you saying all 15 checkboxes are selected?  I'm not sure what you are saying.

Comment: @NewOneInP Please take a moment, write a full explanation of what it is you really want, go through the text to make sure people will understand it and then post/edit your question. At the moment you are saying so many different things that are all hard to understand

Comment: Sorry for my English... For example if i have 15 checkbox and 3 combobox i need to write "if" from 15 check and 3 combo to only 1 check?

Comment: @NewOneInP Well, with so many components, I don't think there is any way of avoiding messy code. But again, it depends on exactly what you are doing. Depending on what/how you are doing you might be able to put  your logic in a loop instead which would be optimal. You could also use listeners on your checkboxes and in each of them do some logic. I wish I could give a better answer, but without access to your code, there is no way

Comment: And you may need to create another question with more details.  What are you really doing?  Do you just want to know the number of checkboxes that are checked?  What if 13 out of 15 of them are checked?

Comment: Mayby this will help u understand what i mean..if (checkBox1.checked)
{
mic.HTMLBody = "1) Example1"
}
else if (checkBox1.checked && checkBox2.checked)
{
mic.HTMLBody = "1) Example1" +"<br>" + "2)Example2"
}
else if (checkBox1.checked && ComboBox1.text == "Pan")
{
mic.HTMLBody = "1) Example1" + "<br>" + "Pana"
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("Something wrong")
}

Comment: And i have 15 checkboxe's and 3 combobox when i can have diffrent combination....

Answer (score 1):

from the code i see if checkbox1.checked is true then "ok1" should display and the second an third evaluations would never be evavluated.  if checkbox1.checked is false then only the third option would be evaluated and the second option should never be evaluated at all. Should be more like:

```
if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("ok2");
            }

       else
           {
                 MessageBox.Show("ok1");
            }
    }
 else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("co nie tak");
    }
```

Comment: You don't need the `checkBox1.Checked && `, as that has already be confirmed, but otherwise this looks like a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Bobajob :)

Answer (score 0):

As it is currently written, it is impossible for it to enter the `else if`, because whenever the `else if` condition is true, the `if` condition is also true.

It goes from up to down, the first that is true is entered and the rest are ignored.

Instead you should switch their place as follows:

```
if(checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ok2");
}
else if(checkBox1.Checked)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ok1");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("co nie tak");
}
```

A little unclear what you really want shown, but if you want it to first show `ok1` and then `ok2` then you can do this:

```
if(checkBox1.Checked)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ok1");
    if(checkBox2.Checked) {
        MessageBox.Show("ok2");
        //MessageBox.Show("ok1 ok2"); //If you want to show them both at the same time
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("co nie tak");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one on a Console and it might be the logic you need. The inline comments will give you a bit of insight of what is doing what:

```
check1 = true;
check2 = true;

if (check1)
{
    if (check2)
    {
        // Prints if BOTH check1 and check2 are TRUE
        Console.WriteLine("ok2");
    }
    else
    {
        // Prints if ONLY check1 is TRUE
        Console.WriteLine("ok1");
    }
}
else
{
    // Prints if BOTH check1 and check2 are FALSE
    Console.WriteLine("co nie tak");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
        bool Check = checkBox1.Checked;
        bool Check2 = checkBox2.Checked;
        if (Check == true && Check2 == true)
        { MessageBox.Show("ok 1 & 2"); }
        if (Check == true) 
        { MessageBox.Show("ok 1"); }
        if (Check2 == true)
        { MessageBox.Show("ok 2 "); }
        else
        { MessageBox.Show("Not Checked"); }
```

Comment: Please don't answer with code without any explanation text. It is not clear why you write this code as an "answer".

Comment: Also, by using only `if` and no `else if` (and adding a "random" `else` at the end) it is not a very efficient solution